# How can I mirror the whole display?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, mirror

I want to be able to mirror my app so it can be viewed in the windshield of a vehicle.

My XML has several nested `LinearLayout`s, `TextView`s and `ImageView`s. Currently I'm transforming each one and although it is mirrored, the structure of the elements is not (what was at the top is now at the bottom).

I've been looking for days and so far have tried a couple of approaches that have failed.

An animation that uses a matrix to flip on the X axis kind of works, except that it either reverts back or it stays and doesn't update, which is no good for interacting with the app.

I just tried to create a custom `LinearLayout` extending the parent one, hoping that I could apply a Matrix in its `onDraw()` method but that gives me a blank screen (I had to set `setWillNotDraw(false);` to hit the `onDraw()`).

Comment: Cool idea. Sounds interesting.

Comment: Hmmm, ok I wonder where the rest of my question went! Needless to say that my last attempt didn't work either and now I'm stumped.

Comment: I was just wondering: would there be a chance to make a change on a lower layer that could mirror the whole system output to the screen? It would definitely require root privileges but for the apps without such feature - a great hack to display them on a windshield.

Answer (score 3):

Well eventually I found a solution that works well for me (so far it's caused no issues for users).

My solution was to override `dispatchDraw` to scale the canvas in my custom LinearLayout. Then I just needed to flip the touch events by overriding `dispatchTouchEvent`:

```
public class CustomContainer extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
    }

    public CustomContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
    }

    public CustomContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        // Flip the view canvas
        if (MyHUDActivity.mHUDMode) canvas.scale(1,-1, getWidth(), getHeight()/2f); 
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas); 
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // If in HUD mode then flip the touch zones
        if (MyHUDActivity.mHUDMode) event.setLocation(event.getX(), getHeight()-event.getY());
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Animation api to deal with reverting back after the horizontal flip.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean that it will stay in its final state and still redraw as if it had not been animated? I better go and look through the docs for this new API.

Comment: i'm not 100% on this one, but if my memory serves me right, yes it does.